# How would one notate the subset of the rationals with terminating decimal expansions?

Tags: notation, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion, convention

Is there a convention for notating a subset of the rationals with restrictions on the denominators? I'd prefer there to be a relatively intuitive and concise notation for the set $\{\frac{n}{10^m}:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ in the ballpark of something along the lines of the following made-up notation: $\mathbb{Q}_{10}$

Comment: You could call it $\frac{\mathbb Z}{10^{\mathbb N_0}}$. There isn't a specific convention for that (that I know of), but there's a general convention that applying operations to sets that are usually applied to its elements yields the set of all elements you could get with any elements from the sets, e.g. $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A\land b\in B\}$. (Note that you shouldn't use $ \mathbb Z/10^{\mathbb N_0}$, since the quotient is defined for rings over ideals and thus might be misunderstood (though in this case that wouldn't make sense since $10^{\mathbb N_0}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb Z$).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ${\Bbb Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ is quite standard. It is used for instance in the definition of the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group):

> ... where ${\Bbb Z}[1/p]$ denotes the group of all rational  numbers
>   whose denominator is a power of p, using addition of rational numbers
>   as group operation

See also this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2102060), where the same notation is used.